# How to implement a custom MIME type for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent?

Tags: java, android, mime

I am using a ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent to launch a system file picker. The user is supposed to be selecting a "gpx" file (blabla.gpx).

I would like to have the picker only allow files with a ".gpx" extension to be selected.

There is a MIME type of "application/gpx+xml", but when I specify that in the intent's settype(), the gpx files are not selectable.

Is there a way to create a custom mime type of "application/gpx", just for use in my app? If so, how do I associate it with the ",gpx" file extension?

Maybe I could change the file extension associated with the "application/gpx+xml" mimne type?

Or, is there another way to accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: `"application/gpx+xml", but when I specify that in the intent's settype(), the gpx files are not selectable.` Very strange. You see them and not selectable? Strange. Here it just does not have any effect. It's like `"*/*"` mimetype.

Comment: It depends on the platrform I am testing on. My Pixel 3 acts as I described above. On my Chromebook, it behaves as you described, as if I had specified "*/*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this to Google, and here is their response:

> A coworker pointed out that application/gpx+xml *is* an established
>   MIME type mapped to the file extension.gpx:
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format
>
> We'll consider adding this mapping to a future version of Android.

Comment: Nice. But what if you want to open an non established MIME type?

Answer (score 1):

> I am using a ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent to launch a system file picker.

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is not limited to files.

> I would like to have the picker only allow files with a ".gpx" extension to be selected.

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is not limited to document providers that use file extensions. And [GPX-formatted content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format) is not limited to files with `.gpx` extensions.

> There is a MIME type of "application/gpx+xml", but when I specify that in the intent's settype(), the gpx files are not selectable.

Try it on an Android SDK emulator or a Google Pixel device. If you encounter the same problem, file a bug report.

However, bear in mind that the roster of MIME types and associated file extensions might be customized by the device manufacturer. That's why I recommend testing on an SDK emulator or Google Pixel, as those are pure Google, so any problems there are Google's responsibility. I agree that `.gpx` is a common file extension for GPX content, so `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` with `application/gpx+xml` should allow the user to pick that content.

> Is there a way to create a custom mime type of "application/gpx", just for use in my app?

No, sorry, at least not in a way that affects `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

> Maybe I could change the file extension associated with the "application/gpx+xml" mimne type?

No, sorry, other than via the bug report that I suggested.

> is there another way to accomplish what I want to do?

Not really.

Comment: I have tested it on a Google Pixel 3 and a Chromebook. When I specify a MIME type of "application/gpx+xml", the Pixel 3 has all files, except directories, grayed out (including any .gpx files). The Chromebook shows all files, the same as if I had specified a mime of "*/*". I am doing my development in Linux on the Chromebook so I can not run any emulators. I will file a bug report. Thanks!

Comment: That's bad. Like the whole document framework.